# Modify Parse Tree

Tags: antlr, antlr4, parse-tree

I have an ANTLR ParseTree for an [sql grammar](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/blob/master/ksqldb-parser/src/main/antlr4/io/confluent/ksql/parser/SqlBase.g4).

Example :[image: Random query]

My goal is to edit this tree so that i can delete all the middle (booleanExpression, predicated, valueExpression, primaryExpression ) nodes inbetween.
I have explored visitor and listenors but they don’t generate the tree for me. And i'd like to not touch the grammar since its the official source one.

So how can i do it?
Thanks

Comment: I'd consider updating your question and explain why you (think you) need this (i.e., this might be an XY-problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you explain the problem you're trying to solve instead, perhaps some other solution is possible without the need to remove certain parts of the tree.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature in ANTLR's API (removing/mutating the `ParseTree`). You'll have to walk the tree yourself and create a copy of the `ParseTree` and ignore certain sub-trees you do not want/need.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve usually found the ParseTree to be too cumbersome (for exactly the reason you’ve shown).  I don’t know of any automated way to alter the tree in memory.  ( Could be an interesting project to attempt.)

I a couple of implementations I’ve written some generalized approach to make the process easier.  The “best” one was where I wrote a small DSL to define the structure I *wanted*.  It generated the classes as well as ANTLR style visitors and listeners for those.  I then used a listener to transform the ANTLR ParseTree to my *ideal* tree, and wrote the rest of my code using that structure with that, much simpler, tree.  You can have a listener/visitor generate a tree of your own design as an artifact of processing the ParseTree, but that’s as close as I’ve come.

It was actually a relatively minor effort to set that up early in the process and accounted for a quite small percentage of the overall effort of implementing the language (so, well worth the effort).